# Changing the range of a Chart in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint-automation

I am experimenting with creating Powerpoint slides out of C#, because I have to create reports out of a tool of mine. The idea to export them to Powerpoint is a given requirement, so I can't change that.

I create and fill a new chart like this:

```
var shape = objSlide.Shapes.AddChart(XlChartType.xlColumnStacked, 200, 200, 300, 300);
myChart = shape.Chart;

Powerpoint.ChartData pChartData = myChart.ChartData;
Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = (Excel.Workbook)pChartData.Workbook;
Excel.Worksheet eWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)eWorkbook.Worksheets[1];

eWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "DATA";
//some more Stuff that is not interesting
```

Now the problem is, that I only need one category, but the default chart creates 3. So I have 3 columns, but I only fill 1 of them. Overwriting them does not work.

**Is there a way to change the range to use (like I do in PPT/EXCEL as well by dragging the blue box)?**

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over the ranges of the shape.chart property - but it's ugly.

Comment: Thats true. But actually, iterating wouldn't solve the Problem. I want to change it. I only find a get Methode for the range.

Answer (score 2):

Note: if someone finds a better solution, please answer :)

I found one (ugly) way to do it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746759.aspx

Unfortunally, the Powerpoint variation of this Method does not use Range objects, but Excel-Selection Strings. So if i would use this Methode i would have to write a Parser which converts:

```
worksheet.Range["A1", "B5"]
```

to

```
"'Tabelle1'!$A$1:$B$5"
```

In the end my Solution would look like:

```
myChart.SetSourceData("'Tabelle1'!$A$1:$B$5", Excel.XlRowCol.xlColumns);
```